# SQL query with "not in" is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have the following SQL query which is very slow. How can I write the script differently?

```
select 
    pws_name 
from 
    pws_asset ass
join 
    Account acc on acc.AccountId = ass.pws_AccountId
where 
    acc.AccountNumber  in ('188012', '172146', '214727', '13636', '201194', '280294', '34328')
    and ass.pws_name not in ('1018684', '1018784', '1019584', '1019784', '1019884', '1070838', '1277139', '1277339'.........)
```

Comment: The first thing to do when attempting to improve a query's performance is to look at the execution plan. Please [edit] your question with a link to your execution plan (You can use Brent Ozar's [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for that.

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: How many values are actually in the `NOT` clause?

Comment: more than 5000 records

Comment: There are some different issues. Firstly you should put index to `AccountNumber` and `pws_name`. Secondly you should look `AccountNumber` and `pws_name` columns types. If column type is different with given value type inside `in` statement you should bring to the same type

Comment: "more than 5000 records" ... you're essentially doing 5000 OR statements .. experiment with putting the data into a temp table (and try indexing that too) and join on it.

Comment: @RodneyEllis that's actually 5000 `and`s, since it' a `not in`. If it was `in`, that it would be 5000 `or`s.

Comment: @biillitil `5000` is no data at all. What does the execution plan look like? Are the `AccountId`, `pws_AccountId`, `AccountNumber` and `pws_name` columns indexed? If not, performance will *always* be bad as the server has to scan all rows in both tables to find matches

Comment: In my experience, the (NOT) IN statement in SQL Server scales notoriously bad. Beyond a couple of thousands of items it gets very slow. See also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks). Therefore. the only solution is to work around it, as in JIKEN's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow below steps, that will help in query performance.

Step 1: DECLARE two variables

```
DECLARE @AccNumList VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PwsNameList VARCHAR(4000)

SET @AccNumList = '188012,172146,214727,13636,201194,280294,34328'
SET @PwsNameList = '1018684,1018784,1019584,1019784,1019884,1070838,1277139,1277339'
```

Step 2: Create two different temporary tables.
1 for account numbers

```
Create table #tblAcNum(AccountNumber VARCHAR(50))
```

2 for pws_name not needed

```
Create table #tblPwsNameNotNeeded(pws_name VARCHAR(50))
```

Step 3: Add records in above two tables which are used in IN and NOT IN.
Please check this [Split csv string using XML in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/) for reference.

```
INSERT INTO #tblAcNum(AccountNumber)
SELECT
l.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') AcNum
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@AccNumList,',','</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AcNumXML
) x
CROSS APPLY x.AcNumXML.nodes('a') Split(l)

INSERT INTO #tblPwsNameNotNeeded(pws_name)
SELECT
l.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') pws_name
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@PwsNameList,',','</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) PwsNameXML
) x
CROSS APPLY x.PwsNameXML.nodes('a') Split(l)
```

Step 3: INNER JOIN #tblAcNum table with account table with accountnumber column

Step 4: Use NOT EXISTS() function for pws_name not needed like below

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM #tblPwsNameNotNeeded pn
Where pn.pws_name = ass.pws_name
)
```

Step 5: Drop temporary tables after your select query.

```
DROP TABLE tblAcNum;
DROP TABLE #tblPwsNameNotNeeded;
```

Please check below query.

```
DECLARE @AccNumList VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PwsNameList VARCHAR(4000)

SET @AccNumList = '188012,172146,214727,13636,201194,280294,34328'
SET @PwsNameList = '1018684,1018784,1019584,1019784,1019884,1070838,1277139,1277339'

Create table #tblAcNum(AccountNumber VARCHAR(50))

Create table #tblPwsNameNotNeeded(pws_name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #tblAcNum(AccountNumber)
SELECT
l.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') AcNum
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@AccNumList,',','</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AcNumXML
) x
CROSS APPLY x.AcNumXML.nodes('a') Split(l)

INSERT INTO #tblPwsNameNotNeeded(pws_name)
SELECT
l.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') pws_name
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@PwsNameList,',','</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) PwsNameXML
) x
CROSS APPLY x.PwsNameXML.nodes('a') Split(l)

select 
ass.pws_name 
from pws_asset ass 
join Account acc on acc.AccountId = ass.pws_AccountId 
INNER JOIN #tblAcNum an ON an.AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM #tblPwsNameNotNeeded pn
Where pn.pws_name = ass.pws_name
)

DROP TABLE tblAcNum;
DROP TABLE #tblPwsNameNotNeeded;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
; with cte_excludepws as
(select AccountId from pws_asset where pws_name not in ('1018684', '1018784', '1019584', '1019784', '1019884', '1070838', '1277139', '1277339'.........))
select 
    pws_name 
from 
    pws_asset ass
join 
    Account acc on acc.AccountId = ass.pws_AccountId
where ass.AccountId not in (select AccountId from cte_excludepws)
and acc.AccountNumber  in ('188012', '172146', '214727', '13636', '201194', '280294', '34328')
```

Alternatively if you can - take the AccountID's into a temporary table instead of cte and create an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that the account *numbers* are really strings.  If they are numbers, drop the single quotes!

Then, for this query

```
select a.pws_name 
from pws_asset a join 
     Account ac 
     on ac.AccountId = a.pws_AccountId
where ac.AccountNumber  in ('188012', '172146', '214727', '13636', '201194', '280294', '34328') and
      a.pws_name not in ('1018684', '1018784', '1019584', '1019784', '1019884', '1070838', '1277139', '1277339'.........);
```

I would recommend indexes on:  `account(accountNumber, AccountId)` and `pws_asset(pws_AccountId, pws_name)`.